# export text then datalist in excel and pdf with dataexporter

Tags: primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.4.2 jar. I have a datatable with four columns. In two columns I have a datalist and I want to export text showed by datalist. But when I export it, it shows the following  "org.primefaces.component.datalist.DataList@1195cc3" in the pdf and xls file.

```
  <p:dataTable emptyMessage="#{messages['empty.result.set']}" id="searchResult" var="row" value="#{managePessoaJuridica.manageableList}" rows="10" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="top" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" style="display:#{managePessoaJuridica.manageableList == null? 'none': ''}">
        <p:column styleClass="column_icons" exportable="false">
            <p:panelGrid columns="#{pessoaJuridicaController.showSelectAction?3:2}">
                <p:commandButton id="selectAction" icon="ui-icon-circle-check" title="#{messages['action.select']}" action="#{pessoaJuridicaController.select(row.id)}" immediate="true" process="@this" rendered="#{pessoaJuridicaController.showSelectAction}"/>
                <p:commandButton id="editAction" icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="#{messages['action.edit']}" action="#{pessoaJuridicaController.load(row.id)}" immediate="true" process="@this" update="@form"/>
                <p:commandButton id="deleteAction" icon="ui-icon-trash" title="#{messages['action.delete']}" action="#{pessoaJuridicaController.delete(row.id)}" immediate="true" process="@this" update="searchResult"
                    onclick="return confirm('#{messages['confirm.delete.this']} #{messages['pessoa.juridica.view.title']}');" />
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:column>

        <p:column id="column_nome" sortBy="#{row.nome}" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText id="columnHeader_nome" value="#{messages['pessoa.nome']}"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText id="nome" value="#{row.nome}">
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>



        <p:column style="width:0px;">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText id="columnHeader_categoriasPessoa" value="#{messages['pessoa.categorias.pessoa']}"/>
            </f:facet>    
                <p:dataList  type="definition" id="categoriasPessoa" var="item" value="#{row.categoriasPessoa}" >
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText id="item_categoriasPessoa" value="#{item}" converter="com.domain.configuracao.crud.CategoriaPessoaJsfConverter"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataList>
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="width:0px;">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText id="columnHeader_identificacoesPessoa" value="#{messages['pessoa.identificacoes.pessoa']}"/>
            </f:facet>
                <p:dataList type="definition" id="identificacoesPessoa" var="item" value="#{row.identificacoesPessoa}">
                    <p:column>
                    <h:outputText id="item_categoriaIdentificacoes" value="#{pessoaJuridicaController.getCategoriaIdentificacao(item)}" converter="com.domain.configuracao.crud.CategoriaIdentificacaoJsfConverter"/>:
                    <h:outputText id="item_identificacoesPessoa" value="#{item}" converter="com.domain.configuracao.crud.IdentificacaoPessoaJsfConverter"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataList>
        </p:column>
                    <p:column id="column_ativo" sortBy="#{row.ativo}" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText id="columnHeader_ativo" value="#{messages['classe.base.cadastro.ativo']}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText id="ativo" value="#{row.ativo}" converter="com.BooleanJsfConverter" >
            </h:outputText>
        </p:column>

         <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:menuButton value="#{messages['export.action']}" rendered="#{not empty managePessoaJuridica.manageableList}">
                <p:menuitem value="#{messages['export.spreadsheet']}" ajax="false">
                    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="searchResult" fileName="export" excludeColumns="0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
                </p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="#{messages['export.pdf']}" ajax="false">
                    <pe:exporter type="pdf" target="searchResult" fileName="export"  excludeColumns="0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
                </p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="#{messages['export.csv']}" ajax="false">
                    <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="searchResult" fileName="export" excludeColumns="0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
                </p:menuitem>
            </p:menuButton>
            <p:spacer width="10"/>
            <h:outputText value="#{fn:length(managePessoaJuridica.manageableList)} #{messages['records.found']}" rendered="#{not empty managePessoaJuridica.manageableList}"/>
        </f:facet>

    </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

> But when I export it, it shows the following
>   "org.primefaces.component.datalist.DataList@1195cc3" in the pdf and
>   xls file.

Obviously, Primefaces's data exporter use the toString() method of an object to print its "value(s)".

Suggestions :

1. Write a custom exporter (*recommended*)
2. Override `toString()` method of `org.primefaces.component.datalist.DataList` (*not advised*)

Comment: For XLS I found this : http://ontheroadofjava.blogspot.ch/2008/09/export-excel-file-under-jsf.html and for PDF it is also very easy using iText or JasperReport, just try to google mate.